# AFNetworking EXC_BAD_ACCESS in setCompletionBlock

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, afnetworking

I'm working on an iOS app and am having some trouble with making a http request using AFNetworking.

When I run the code I get the error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2 address=0x0).
The error is occurring when I attempt to setCompletionBlock.

I'm new to Objective-C and this has me stumped.

Thank you in advance. Everyone's help is appreciated!

```
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>
#import "UploadImg.h"

@implementation UploadImg

- (void) uploadImg:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.com/mobile/"];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:[arguments objectAtIndex:1]];

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [params setObject:@"TEST_STYLE" forKey:@"styleType"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/upload.php" parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"imageName" fileName:@"image.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
    }];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];

    [operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"success");
    } 
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error");
    }];

    [operation start];
}

@end
```

[image]

Thanks again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to solve this by changing the build settings.

Under the linking header change the "Other linker flags", click the entry for -weak_library and replace it with -weak-lSystem

From question: [Use of Blocks crashes app in iPhone Simulator 4.3/XCode 4.2 and 4.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738858/use-of-blocks-crashes-app-in-iphone-simulator-4-3-xcode-4-2-and-4-0-2)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the fun world of Objective-C, @kev_addict!

When you get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception, it helps to have the details, to see what the stack trace looks like for the offending call.

Without any additional information, my gut tells me that your problems lie somewhere in the way you're getting the image data from an array. Is there any reason why you wouldn't have this method take a `UIImage` argument? It seems odd to expect that this method takes an array that expects image data--in the second position, no less.

Comment: Hello Mattt, thanks for replying. I added a screenshot, please let me know if I'm looking in the wrong place for the stack trace. This is the native portion of a plugin that I'm working on for a phonegap/cordova app. So it's getting called from a javascript file and I'm passing in a base64 encoded png as the second argument. Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: Out of curiosity I hardcoded the base64 image string rather than getting it from the method arguments and got the same error. When I comment out the  `operation setCompletionBlock...` portion the error does not occur...